# Как прервать 3rd-party код?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net-core

Есть 3rd-party код из библиотеки который "зависает" в ожидании где-то в работе с сетью. `CancellationToken` поддержки нет, таймаутов нет. Запускаю я его через:

```
Task.Run(() => FooWith3rdPart());
```

Первая идея была сделать харакири:

```
void FooWith3rdPart() {
    new Timer(Thread.CurrentThread.Abort, null, 1000, -1);
    // here stuck code
}
```

Но в netcore отсуствует `CurrentThread.Abort`.

Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: Хороший и правильный способ - сделать обертку вокруг этой либы в виде отдельного приложения. Теперь, в случае, если оно зависнет, всегда можно прибить приложение.

Comment: Вы не должны запускать код, которому вы не доверяете, в своём процессе. Потому что запущенный в вашем процессе код может сделать вообще всё. Например, остановить все потоки или крешнуться.

Comment: @VladD автор вроде бы не выражал никакого недоверия :). Просто библиотека не поддерживает отмену и таймауты, а по требованиям такая потребность есть. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: @andreycha: Ну, если код виснет, то он плохо отлажен, так что я бы не стал ему доверять. Может быть, если поверить автору, код не будет сознательно вредить, но он вполне может повредить неосознанно.

Comment: @andreycha: Ну а если библиотека хорошая, но просто не поддерживает отмену/таймауты, то тогда она не подходит для проекта, и надо искать новую или писать свою.

Comment: @VladD библиотека она плохая, но других нет. ибо это клиент, к закрытому HTML2PDF конвертеру.

Comment: Если библиотека вам не подходит, не нужно пытаться <s>натянуть сову на глобус</s> её использовать. Не подходит — скажите начальнику честно, что не подходит. Насчёт того, что других нету, гугл с вами не согласен. Вот [первая же ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/) с обзором.

Comment: Если вдруг вопрос ещё актуален, посмотрите [у коллег](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080995/net-core-1-0-equivalent-for-system-threading-thread-currentthread-managedthread)

Comment: @ОлексійЛогвиненко если вопрос еще актуален - то выносите в отдельный процесс! Эти чертовы HTML2PDF конвертеры еще и памяти жрут до черта, и не всегда отдают. обратно

Comment: @VladD в общем случае ваш совет правильный - но конкретно к HTML2PDF конвертерам он не подходит. Конвертеров с нормальной архитектурой попросту нет. Они все реализованы на основе тех или иных браузеров - а браузеров на C# не пишут...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Если так, возможно, имеет смысл не идти через HTML, а генерировать данные прямо в PDF, используя библиотеку для генерации PDF (по крайней мере в нашем проекте мы делаем именно так).